# Как получить полный код со страницы?

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Требуется получить **ВЕСЬ** код с сайта такого формата  https://www.chess.com/game/live/40471234963, а именно в любом виде позицию **ВСЕХ** фигур на доске. Пробовал использовать bs4 и requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.chess.com/game/live/40471234963")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

print(soup.get_text)
```

Но в выводе нет нужной информации. Возможно нужно использовать другую библиотеку или кодировку?

P.S Нашел нужный XPath для получения FEN позиции, но не знаю как его получить(

`xpath = "/html/body/div[8]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[3]"`

Comment: На сайте есть ссылка 'download', при нажатии на которую происходит экспорт pgn. требуется извлечь яваскрипт, который её обрабатывает и возвращает результат, и работать непосредственно с ними

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучшее, что можно использовать в этом случае - *Selenium*. С ним можно удобно добираться до `JS`-фрагментов и потом их обрабатывать.

Answer (score 1):

Там есть такой фрагмент:

```
<!--/Hover Square-->

<.... тут непонятно что ...>

<div class="piece br square-48" style=""></div>
<div class="piece bp square-27" style=""></div>
<div class="piece bk square-17" style=""></div>
<div class="piece bp square-85" style=""></div>
<div class="piece wp square-65" style=""></div>
<div class="piece wp square-55" style=""></div>
<div class="piece bp square-15" style=""></div>
<div class="piece wq square-54" style=""></div>
<div class="piece bp square-43" style=""></div>
<div class="piece bq square-23" style=""></div>
<div class="piece wp square-82" style=""></div>
<div class="piece wb square-72" style=""></div>
<div class="piece wk square-81" style=""></div>
<div class="piece wr square-41" style=""></div>
<div class="piece wr square-31" style=""></div>
<!--/Pieces-->
<!--/MoveHints-->
<!--/Capture Hints-->
```

Число - численная координата клетки. 11 это а1, 81 это h1, 88 это h8, 23 - b3.

Двухбуквенная аббревиатура - что стоит на этой клетке. Первая буква - цвет:

- w - белая (white)
- b - черная (black)

Вторая буква - фигура:

- p - пешка (pawn),
- b - слон (bishop),
- n - конь (knight),
- r - ладья (rook),
- q - ферзь (queen),
- k - король (king).

*Но, похоже, это все яваскрипт и в результате запроса bs этого нет, т.к. там скрипт не исполняется.*

Comment: Согласен, но факт остается фактом что непонятно как это достать...

Comment: Так уже написали как достать, а там записаны все ходы